# How can I change a R script file to a lowercase r file extension?

Tags: r

I am trying to change a R script file to a lowercase r file extension? My script file at looks like this when created on the MacOS version of RStudio.

```
Test_File.R
```

I have read that this can cause a permission denied error. Is there an easy way to change this to a lowercase r file extension? Such as...

```
Test_File.r
```

I have tried renaming the file extension for 'R' to 'r' in Finder but I am not sure whether renaming the file extension to 'r' in Finder is enough?

Comment: Do it at the commandline? Use `rename` or `sed`? Or use `list.files` with some regex(permission issue here)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R can do it the following way:

```
x <- list.files(pattern = "\\.R$") # make sure to set working directory first
file.rename(x, sub("R$", "r", x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Save these all command into a text.file suppose you save in (rename_shell_script)

```
ls *R > list 
cp list list1
sed -i 's/.R/.r/g' list1
paste list list1| sed 's/^/mv /g' |sh
```

run it like :
$sh rename_shell_script

Comment: ++ve for your efforts, but why we need a long script, when problem can be solve with single line command.

Answer (score 1):

for linux terminal users:     #make sure you are in working directory first

```
rename 's:(.*)\.R:$1.r:g' *.R
```

Use filename in place of * if you want to make change in the single file only.